# Red Shading On my LCD screen, red lines only on black color (see pic), help

Tags: graphics-card, display, lcd

There are red lines all over when there is something black on my desktop LCD screen. Is this a problem with my LCD or my Graphics Card or something. I have Inter G33/G31 Express Chipset Family Graphics Card, as I can see. And I have also installed its latest driver from the download center of intel. I have an acerv 203HV LCD. What is the problem ? Here is the of my screen playing video, th epic is taken from my mobile camera...[image]

Another Example Image[image]

Comment: I need to have 10 reputation to post pic, I didn't know that...

Comment: You can still post the link as text, just indent it four space.

Comment: Now, I have added the picture, can anyone tell what's the problem, is it my LCD hardware or my Videocard or something ?

Comment: Anyone plz tell me what is the problem with my screen ?

Comment: any expert here ?

Comment: That looks like a full-screen video. Does the same thing happen on the desktop or full-screen games or the black-and-white boot screen when you first turn it on?

Comment: Please add the computer make (Acer?) & model to the original post along with the operating system you are using

Answer (score 2):

That looks more like a rendering problem than a display problem which points to drivers/graphics chip. I would not use the Intel drivers as OEMs use the chipsets differently depending on the hardware they are connected to. Go the OEM website for the motherboard/graphics card and download their drivers.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help, but I need little more help. Where do I find OEM graphics drivers ?

Comment: You need the make/model of the graphics card itself(or the motherboard if it's on-board graphics), not just the chipset.

Comment: The Model of my Motherboard is X31_ICH7. By the way, how do I know that it is on-board graphics. And How do I know the make/model of the graphics card. Well, I am using some software named Speccy to know about this problem.

Comment: Is this an IBM laptop?

Comment: No its a Desktop (Assembled)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the tag. Please add the model of the PC to your original post. Also include the Operating system

Comment: You could post an image of your speccy details. If not, then under the "Graphics" section you should find a listing for what is running your graphics and post it here.

Comment: the problem has gone, after installing new windows 7...!

Comment: That points to the drivers you were using.

Answer (score 0):

When my displays go a little crazy I try doing:

1. Make sure all plugs are plugged in correctly
2. Test with another display
3. Test with another cable
4. Update display drivers

Also, out of curiosity, what were you watching in the second picture?

Comment: oh its the G.I. Joe Rise Of Cobra Movie.....:)